# Make periodic HTTP requests with service worker

Tags: service-worker

Is it possible to make HTTP requests in background with service worker, when users are not visiting my webpage. I want to make periodic requests to my webpage (e.g. 3 seconds)?

There is a feature called **periodicSync**, but i didn't understand how to use it.

Comment: Note that periodicSync is not on a standards track and is currently only supported in Chrome >=43. It's not something you'd want to use for any essential functionality on a public website.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried implementing this but for me the clearest overview has been this [explanation](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md).

Making periodic requests involves first handling the Service Worker `ready` event, invoking the periodicSync.register() function with config options. The `register()` function returns a Promise that allows you to deal with success or rejection of the periodic sync registration.

`registration.periodicSync.register()`

Pass a 'config' object parameter with the following properties:

- tag
- minPeriod
- powerState
- networkState

You may then register listeners against the `periodicSync` event. E.g (slightly simplified example based on the [explanation](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md).

```
self.addEventListener('periodicsync', function(event) {
  if (event.registration.tag == 'my-tag') {
    event.waitUntil(doTheWork()); // "do the work" asynchronously via a Promise.
  }
  else {
    // unknown sync, may be old, best to unregister
    event.registration.unregister();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i still didn't understand how to use this code block. How do i set a timer? How can make a http request?

Comment: Look at the parameters for the register function: minPeriod. That specifies how often the event will be raised.